# Nested Powershell Function

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I want to try and automate server decommission procedures because the current task is too manual. So I have two functions. Function 1 stores the domain admins credentials and function 2 executes the decom procedures.

```
Function decom{

Set-Variable domain,password -Scope Global

function user {
$user =Read-Host -Prompt "Enter user name"
$domain = "domain\"+$user
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter domain password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-String | Set-Content C:\test\password.txt


}
user

$remove_AD = Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -RemoveDnsDelegation -NoRebootOnCompletion New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $domain, $password -WhatIf
$remove_Domain = Remove-Computer -UnjoinDomainCredential New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $domain, $password -WhatIf
$remove_NetAdapter = Disable-NetAdapter -Name * -WhatIf
}decom
```

Comment: What is your question? Which error is thrown and what have you tried to get around it?

Comment: I'd put a heck of alot more error checking in, whatever your current problem is....